# Waypoint.js: Add class when N distance to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I dont know if it is easy or not, but i just cant figure out something with Waypoint.js
I need to add a class to #stickytop when user reach, for ex, 100px of scroll
Any idea how to do this?
offset is not working for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really the use case for jQuery waypoints. It's designed for testing how far specific elements are from the top of the screen, not how far a user has scrolled.

However you can easily do what you want with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    // if the scroll distance is greater than 100px
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
      // do something
      $('#stickytop').addClass('myClass');
    }
});
```

Or vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () { 
  if (window.scrollY > 100) {
    var el = document.getElementById('#stickytop');
    el.className = el.className + " myClass";
  }
})
```